# is google seeing my keyword as boiler plate text

Tags: google

My webmaster tools is telling me that the search term

mini diggers

is not a content keyword, Diggers is but mini diggers is not listed.

Yet the search queries has this as the 10th most popular search query. This leads me to assume that google is viewing the word mini as boilerplate text, see answer

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35255

Does anyone know of a way to tell if this is the case?

Site:

www.contractorshire.co.uk

Answer (score 1):

Content Keywords within Google Webmaster Tools does not display keyword phrases and keyword phrases are made up of more than 2 keywords. Some words are simply ignored in the Content Keywords, these include 'Web' which is not a stop word.

**From Google's Mouth:**

> The Keywords list will sometimes exclude words that we determine to be
>   boiler plate text or common words.

Google as you know is pretty broad at times in what is what, but going back to the word 'Web' I assume 'Mini' is also a common word (But it's not a stop word) because Mini is used to describe a object/item Mini Lop, Mini Digger, Mini Car, etc etc. So I believe this is the case, and another thing said by Google:

> Google explains that although it may not show up in the report, due to
>   possible Google issues, this should not impact the site in a negative
>   way.

**Page Issues with Mini Digger**

I took a look at the page mini digger page and thought I'd give some constructive advice, you could increase the use of the word `mini digger` once or twice more to give it more relevance. The other problem I stopped is the page could be incorrectly being processed by Google - This page and not investigating the others for example has 37 Errors, and 6 warnings on W3 Validator, while some are not so serious, sadly some are because the tags are not closed and this can cause all type of problems.

One small minor problem that should be easy to fix is that on your pages you are using `&` while this isn't a serious problem as I'm sure Google has things in place for pages which contain invalid characters its best to fix the problem so you can move onto the next problems. Change all usage of `&` to `&amp;`.

Additionally you may want to look into the headers of the page because they are not being processed correctly - for example at present if your trying to rank for the phrase `Mini Diggers Reading` then this could be a problem because your headers are actually processing as `Mini Digger Hire inReading, London& Surrounding areas` and Google may be ranking you for inreading without the space.. You can take a look [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aBvtEOpIMLsoJ%3awww.contractorshire.co.uk/plant/mini-digger-hire.asp%2bwww.contractorshire.co.uk/plant/mini-digger-hire.asp&hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&prmd=ivns&strip=1). Additionally you can check the errors I found at [w3](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.contractorshire.co.uk/plant/mini-digger-hire.asp&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).

I hope you don't mind me taking a look and I know this wasn't your main question and you might even be aware of the problem but thought I'd add in my 2 cents, since your question relates to SEO it may be in your interest to fix the on page problems.

Comment: Hi - I certainly do not mind, I really appreciate the advice. I will digest it and come back - Thanks!